# Synthesis of Hydrogen Fluoride

Tags: acid-base, synthesis

At almost 300°C, $\ce{CaF2}$ reacts with sulfuric acid and this reaction produces $\ce{HF}$. Is there any way to make a relatively dilute (10-20%) hydrofluoric acid with $\ce{CaF2}$ as the source of fluoride ions without that much amount of heat?

Comment: CaF2 is already source of F- anions.

Comment: But the synthesis described above is too dangerous to be safe to do in my lab. Of course I know that $CaF_{2}$ is a source of $F^{-}$ ions.

Comment: Well, if you really need acid, then better buy it.

Comment: But I do not need even 100ml of a 5% solution of it and I do not want to store that much of such a nasty chemical which I won't need anymore

Comment: Hmm, then you might borrow a bit ;) Well what you mention is rather industrial method, but it shouldn't be hard to find lab version.

Comment: Well If I find or experiment a safer method for directly producing the dilute acid I will post it here as an answer :)

Comment: HF *is* pretty nasty stuff... can you substitute something such as ammonium acid fluoride, NH4HF2 (which is almost as bad, admittedly)?

Answer (score 2):

In desperation, for some unknown reason, I need 15% aqueous $\ce{HF}$. What do I really need? A weak solution of $\ce{H+}$, say about pH 2. And a solution of fluoride ions to wreak havoc on some unsuspecting metal or glass(Ooops, I may have given away the secret).

My subconscious suggests that I could get them from two different sources, like $\ce{NaF}$ and $\ce{HCl}$. Yeah, that'll work.

Maybe. Maybe even with $\ce{CaF2}$(The use of $\ce{H2SO4}$ with the calcium salt suggests the reason was to precipitate the $\ce{CaSO4}$ and flash off the $\ce{HF}$, thereby separating, not just generating, the $\ce{HF}$).